# limit number of SCSS files compiled

Tags: sass, gruntjs, compass

have a folder with 4 SCSS files, I only want to compile one of them on a normal basis. THe others are themed versions of that SCSS file.

Here is the grunt part for my compass. Does anyone know how I can achieve this ?

```
compass: {
            build: {
                options: {
                    sassDir: 'app/scss',
                    cssDir: 'build/css',
                    imagesDir: 'app/images',
                    outputStyle: 'compressed',  //expanded or nested or compact or compressed
                    httpStylesheetsPath: '/',
                    raw: 'Sass::Script::Number.precision = 16\n',
                    noLineComments: true,
                    relativeAssets: true
                }
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [specify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass#specify).

```
compass: {
        build: {
            options: {
                sassDir: 'app/scss',
                cssDir: 'build/css',
                specify: 'build/css/file.scss'
                imagesDir: 'app/images',
                outputStyle: 'compressed',  //expanded or nested or compact or compressed
                httpStylesheetsPath: '/',
                raw: 'Sass::Script::Number.precision = 16\n',
                noLineComments: true,
                relativeAssets: true
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: can I then have different task like the build. Fx build, anotherBuild, where each have its seperate options, because when I try this, grunt runs both. Eventhough I write compass:build